# up button from preference fragment to return to preference headers

Tags: android, navigation, preferencescreen

My app has preference headers on which you choose what fragment to start. After you are in some fragment I want that click on back button shows header again and if I press back again when headers are shown to return me to some other activity.

I overridded `onOptionsItemSelected` in Activity and in Fragment but it always calls action from activity because I am trying to bind fragment and activity to same action. Here is my code:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {
@Override
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preference_headers, target);
}

@Override
protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
    return SettingsFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setupActionBar();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void setupActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}



public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.app_preferences);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by removing `onOptionsItemSelected` method from activity and leave inside fragment. Now when I press up inside fragment it goes to `SettingsActivity` and when up is pressed inside activity it acts like `onBackPressed()`. Hope this helps somebody.